# WP8 Pull to Refresh inside Pivot

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, telerik, refresh, pivot

I am trying to add a Pull to Refresh `RadControl` from Telerik within a `PivotItem` in WP8.

This is the code:

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Title" Foreground="Black">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle>
        <Style TargetType="telerikListBox:PullToRefreshIndicatorControl">
            <Setter Property="RefreshTimeLabelFormat" Value="last refresh time: {0:H:mm}"/>
        </Style>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Error messages:

> The property 'PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle' does not exist on the type
>   'PivotItem' in the XML namespace`
>
> The attachable property 'PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle' was not found in
>   type 'RadDataBoundListBox'.
>
> The member "PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle" is not recognized or is not
>   accessible.

How do I get this to work within the `PivotItem` control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are missing some tags. Aren't you suppose to have the telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox defined within the pivot item?'

Like such:

```
<phone:PivotItem Header="Title" Foreground="Black">
    <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
        <telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle>
            <Style TargetType="telerikListBox:PullToRefreshIndicatorControl">
               <Setter Property="RefreshTimeLabelFormat" Value="last refresh time:{0:H:mm}"/>
            </Style>
        </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox.PullToRefreshIndicatorStyle>
    </telerikPrimitives:RadDataBoundListBox>
</phone:PivotItem>
```

Comment: I added `telerikPrimitives:` in the PivotItem but it didn't recognise `RadDataBoundListBox`.

Comment: I meant that it was missing the control itself. I updated the answer